# Angular: how to do *ngFor for associative array

Tags: angular7

dataJSON  (array)
`dataList.const.ts`
https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb28b09d

`component.html`

//1st `*ngFor` (worked
<tr *ngFor="let item of list">
{{item.city.id}}
{{item.city.name}}
{{item.city.coord.lon}}
{{item.city.coord.lat}}
{{item.city.country}}
{{item.city.population}}

[image]

//2nd `*ngFor` (cannot display)

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list">
        <td>
      {{item.list_}}
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.temp.day}} °C
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.temp.min}} °C
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.temp.max  }} °C
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.temp.night  }} °C
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.temp.eve  }} °C
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.temp.morn  }} °C
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.pressure}} hpa
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.humidity}} %
        </td>
        <td>
              {{item.list_.weather.id }}
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.weather.main }}
        </td>
        <td >
      {{item.list_.weather.description }}
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.weather.icon }}
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.speed}} meter/sec
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.deg}} °
        </td>
        <td>
      {{item.list_.clouds}} %
        </td>
        <td>
              {{item.list_.rain}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look into this: [ngFor inside ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921096/ngfor-inside-ngfor)

Basically you should write something like this:

```
*ngFor = "let item of list"
```

And then

```
*ngFor = "let l of item.list_"
```

Then use

```
<td>{{l.temp.night}}</td>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-pnuhfh

This is a stackblitz example for your answer, based on your feedback comments.

The relevant code snippet is:

```
<tr *ngFor = "let item of fetchData">
  <td *ngFor = "let l of item.list_">
    {{l.dt}}|
    {{l.temp.night}}|
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: mate I tried to be :  (unfortunately its not worked)
`
<tr *ngFor="let item of list." >
   <td *ngFor = "let l of item.list_">
          {{l.temp.night}}
   </td>
<tr>
`

Comment: Yes. Is your problem is how to fit that in a table?

Comment: yeah thats my question : how to fit that in a table? T_T

Comment: Then this is probably the answer you are looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860933/ngif-and-ngfor-on-td-td-element

Comment: See I have updated my answer with an example. I did not use `ng-container`.

Comment: thanks mate I tried both solution and still cannot display the data

Comment: oh man you're a very nice guy. tq but still have problemT_T
let me show you the console.error
https://imgur.com/a/WUYxoOW

Comment: Is it `l` in `{{l.temp.night}}`? From the screenshot, it looks like `1` (one).

Comment: bro u r the best. list_dt can display now but list_.temp.night cannot

Comment: Thanks dear. Now I am at my wit's end; if list_.dt can be displayed, then so will list_.temp.night, given that your data has the fields. Can you try `{{l.temp?.night}}` and `{{l?.temp.night}}`? Don't mess `l` with `1`.

Comment: bro @SoumyaKanti ive got another angular practice now. my Q now : how to upgrade the code from angular js to angular 7. Here is my exercise: jsbin.com/gumaraz/edit?html,output Any idea?

Comment: I think that is completely different question. You may do some google - I have no experience in such migration. If the search does not help, consider logging a new question in Stackoverflow.

Comment: okay bro~may i ask u  why the manager deleted my post which i have written my ans

Comment: I think it was a screenshot rather than text. The community standard is to contain everything / as much as possible within stackoverflow itself.

Comment: so sad that i changed to text and they still deleted it , well is okay i just want to help ppl who hv the same problem

Comment: Yes, sometimes this is weird, some folks become overactive and think stackoverflow as their personal property and take it personally. I too faced such behaviors in the past. Despite that, it is still a nice platform to seek help and learn.